# In MVVM Controller doesn't exist physically ? Doesn't this violate the Separation of Concerns Principle?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, architecture, frameworks

I can't see it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx

How do you want to separate concerns then if controller is mixed with view-model ? controller is not reduced to just databinding there is also commands.

I mean if MVVM also has the responsability of a controller then this design violates the principle of Separation of concerns. Maintaining state of the view and orchestrating logics of View and Model are clearly 2 big tasks that should be separate and that's the reason behind C of MVC

So what if I want to have a separate controller: how hard it would be as WPF and silverlight makes GUI load first without allowing invisible class to load first like controller and then manage the view and model ?

Comment: Isn't that so ViewModel serves as Controller in MVVM?

Comment: My point is that it shouldn't : it violates the principle of Separation of concerns. Maintaining state of the view and orchestrating logics of View and Model are clearly 2 big tasks that should be separate and that's the reason behind C of MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you looking at this in with respect to the MVC pattern rather than looking at this in a separation of concerns angle? The way I see it, your question compares MVVM to MVC.

There are different approaches to MVVM: View-First, ViewModel first and Marriage type. I marriage type you can have another class that marriages these the View and the ViewModel. The said class loads first before anything, instanciates View and ViewModel then marriages both.

```
public class SomeScreen : ScreenBase, IScreen
    {
        [Import(typeof(ISomeViewModel))]
        public IViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return this.GetPropertyValue(ApplicationProperties.ViewModel); }
            set {
                this.SetPropertyValue(ApplicationProperties.ViewModel, value);
                RaisePropertyChanged(ApplicationProperties.ViewModel);
            }
        }

        #region Constructor
        public MainScreen()
        {
            CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public override IView GetViewToDisplay()
        {
            IView view = new MainView();
            //Or maybe have a mechanism here based on settings which view to pair up with this.
            view.ViewModel = this.ViewModel;
            this.ViewModel.View = view;
            return view;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

With this example, there would be a total separation between them and no dependencies because of the interfaces and you can add a whole lot of functionalities to the screen/controller too.

Comment: Aren't you looking at this in with respect to the MVC pattern rather than looking at this in a separation of concerns angle? No because Original MVC did care about separation of concerns whereas MVVM implementation does mix some part of controller with view and with model-view just because GUI is first class citizen and not model. But thanks for your sample code : yes i prefer the marriage type.

Comment: I see... Must have misunderstood your questions a little bit. Hope the code helps. :)